# How can I remove A friends phone from my google account? I used it and didn't sign out

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have been on the security manager page and although the device is there, there is no option to remove it or deauthorise it. I have changed my password but am unsure if they can still gain access without needing a password as I have just clicked on my phone to gmail and it opened without needing a password. I'm not good with computers so don't know what else to do. Help would be appreciated x

Answer (score 2):

If you changed your password, your account is signed out everywhere and requires the password to log in again. All is safe.

Answer (score 0):

Ethan's answer is correct, but for peace of mind: You can also log in to Gmail on your PC, hit "Details" at the very bottom-right of the page, and choose "Sign out all other sessions".

Answer (score 0):

If you are really worried about security you can go for [Google two step verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/)

Everytime you sign in from any device or anywhere you will be asked for OTP.
It gives another layer of security to your account.